# How to create jms message queue in jboss 6 using Activemq?

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I have configured activemq in jboss referring this [link](http://activemq.apache.org/integrating-apache-activemq-with-jboss.html). After configured i want to create sample queue in jboss server.After that how to create sample queue in jboss? 
I have used following file for configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE connection-factories
    PUBLIC "-//JBoss//DTD JBOSS JCA Config 1.5//EN"
    "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-ds_1_5.dtd">

<connection-factories>

   <tx-connection-factory>
      <jndi-name>activemq/QueueConnectionFactory</jndi-name>
      <xa-transaction/>
      <track-connection-by-tx/>
      <rar-name>activemq-ra.rar</rar-name>
      <connection-definition>javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory</connection-definition>
      <ServerUrl>vm://localhost</ServerUrl>
      <!--
      <UserName>sa</UserName>
      <Password></Password>
      -->
      <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
      <max-pool-size>200</max-pool-size>
      <blocking-timeout-millis>30000</blocking-timeout-millis>
      <idle-timeout-minutes>3</idle-timeout-minutes>
   </tx-connection-factory>

   <tx-connection-factory>
      <jndi-name>activemq/TopicConnectionFactory</jndi-name>
      <xa-transaction/>
      <track-connection-by-tx/>
      <rar-name>activemq-ra.rar</rar-name>
      <connection-definition>javax.jms.TopicConnectionFactory</connection-definition>
      <ServerUrl>vm://localhost</ServerUrl>
      <!--
      <UserName>sa</UserName>
      <Password></Password>
      -->
      <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
      <max-pool-size>200</max-pool-size>
      <blocking-timeout-millis>30000</blocking-timeout-millis>
      <idle-timeout-minutes>3</idle-timeout-minutes>
   </tx-connection-factory>

   <mbean code="org.jboss.resource.deployment.AdminObject" name="activemq.queue:name=outboundQueue">
      <attribute name="JNDIName">activemq/queue/outbound</attribute>
      <depends optional-attribute-name="RARName">jboss.jca:service=RARDeployment,name='activemq-ra.rar'</depends>
      <attribute name="Type">javax.jms.Queue</attribute>
      <attribute name="Properties">PhysicalName=queue.outbound</attribute>
   </mbean>

   <mbean code="org.jboss.resource.deployment.AdminObject" name="activemq.topic:name=inboundTopic">
      <attribute name="JNDIName">activemq/topic/inbound</attribute>
      <depends optional-attribute-name="RARName">jboss.jca:service=RARDeployment,name='activemq-ra.rar'</depends>
      <attribute name="Type">javax.jms.Topic</attribute>
      <attribute name="Properties">PhysicalName=topic.inbound</attribute>
   </mbean>

</connection-factories>
```

This file named as activemq-jms-ds.xml  and deployed in jboss/server/default/deploy folder.

How to create queue in jboss server using activemq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot comment on the correctness of the configuration you posted. But in general ActiveMQ creates queues and topics dynamically whenever a client connection is opened to a destination that does not exist yet. See the [ActiveMQ Howto](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-create-new-destinations.html).